# Formula needed: copy cell, omitting text before and after an item

Tags: excel-formula

@AlexP
Need to copy "AAAA-BBBB-CCCC" while removing the specific text string before "AAAA-", and removing everything after "CCCC" (everything after C begins with " assign" and is variable text after that constant)

"AAAA", "BBBB" and "CCCC" represent text strings that are variable in characters and number of characters.

Cell to copy: 
"specific text string here**AAAA-BBBB-CCCC** assign and variable text string after"

Result of formula: AAAA-BBBB-CCCC

[image: copy K to H]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as long as the specific text in the beginning does not contain `assign` then use this:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(A1,FIND("assign",A1)-1),"Specific Text String Here","")
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you!  Perfect! @Scott-Craner